# Playing music with audio normalize using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I’m trying to play a music with volume normalization, applyied by iVolume.

The music play 1 or 2 seconds and just after apply the volume normalization. Apparently the music is correctly, on native iPod player works fine.

After two days searching and testing, I can’t find any solution or tips.

I’m using AVAudioPlayer, because I need to get external audios.

Follow the music:
https://db.tt/52qohzJn

Piece of code:

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
NSError *setAVError = nil;

NSString *path      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/02GreenDay.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL    *soundUrl  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];

_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: soundUrl error:&setAVError];
 NSLog(@"Error: %@",[setAVError localizedDescription]);


AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];


if (![session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                    error:&setCategoryError])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[setCategoryError localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Error AudioSession");
}

[session setActive:YES error:nil];

[_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

The _audioPlayer is a property.

Any ideas?

Thanks!